# How to calculate percentage properly

Tags: python, pandas

I have three dataframes that have column "City". All three dataframes have a different set of city names.

I want to find the percentage of total matches between this column of each dataframe.

For this purpose I used set method and got three arrays

```py
set1 = set(df1['City'])
set2 = set(df2['City'])
set3 = set(df3['City'])
```

But how should I find the percentage?
I used these functions, but I'm not sure I did everything right

```py
(len(set1) - len(set2))/len(set1)*100
(len(set1) - len(set3))/len(set1)*100
(len(set2) - len(set3))/len(set2)*100
```

Is this record right?

Comment: You're just getting the size difference between the sets, not matching the elements. I think you meant `len(set1 - set2)` instead of `let(set1) - len(set2)`

Comment: Also, that's the percentage of *different* elements, not the percentage of matches. To get the matches, use the intersection, not difference.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
percentage = ( len(set1.intersection(set2)) / len(set1.union(set2)) )*100
```

which gives you the percentage of common elements in `set1` and `set2`.

This is also known as [Jaccard Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index), a measurement for similarity of sets.

Answer (score 0):

From the pure mathimatical side of things:
I assume that you want to find the percentage of cities matching between respectively set1 & set2, set1 & set3 and set2 & set3.

To calculate this percentage, you need to find the number of matches and the length of the set of cities compared.

Then the percentage can be calculated as follows:

Percentage match 1 & 2 = [(number of matches between 1 & 2)/(length of the set)]*100

For the code side of things: i agree with Sparkofska.